# RethinkDB connect AttributeError

Tags: python, connect, rethinkdb, attributeerror

I'm trying to make a wrapper module for the RethinkDB API and I've come across an AttributeError when importing my class(called rethinkdb.py). I'm working in a virtual machine having a shared folder 'Github'.

I do this in IPython console:

```
import library.api.rethinkdb as re
```

This is the error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 1, in 
>       import library.api.rethinkdb as re
>
> File "/media/sf_GitHub/library/api/rethinkdb.py", line 51,
>   in 
>       conn = Connection().connect_to_database()
>
> File "/media/sf_GitHub/library/api/rethinkdb.py", line 48,
>   in connect_to_database
>       raise e
>
> AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'connect'

This is the code:

```
import rethinkdb as r  #The downloaded RethinkDB module from http://rethinkdb.com/

class Connection(object):
    def __init__(self, host='127.0.0.1', port=28015, database=None, authentication_key=''):
        self.host = host
        self.port = port
        if database is None:
            self.db = 'test'
        self.auth_key = authentication_key

    def connect_to_database(self):
        try:
            conn = r.connect(self.host, self.port, self.db, self.auth_key)
        except Exception, e:
            raise e
        return conn    

conn = Connection().connect_to_database()
```

Comment: Turns out I was importing my own module in the de code instead of the downloaded one due to having the same name for my module.
Quick solved it by renaming my module.

Answer (score 6):

I ran into something similar today and I noticed the authors have changed basic behavior of the API in the later versions.

From what I have tested on my machine:

v2.3.0

```
import rethinkdb as r
r.connect()
```

v2.4.1

```
import rethinkdb as r
rdb = r.RethinkDB()
rdb.connect()
```

Answer (score 4):

It worked for me when I ran:

```
import rethinkdb as rdb
r = rdb.RethinkDB()
r.connect('localhost', 28015).repl()
```